# Query to sort the time with date in descending order in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, date, time

I am trying to sort the order date in descending order but here the date is comming in decending order but the time is not comming in the said order.

My query :

```
SELECT get_sub_test_name(test_id, sub_test_id) as testname,
       quantity, status, receipt_no, cash_book,            
       to_char(m.requi_date,'dd/mm/yyyy hh:MIAM') AS orderdate,  
       r.service_type, r.volume, r.requi_id, r.requi_year
FROM recommended_test as r , requisition_main as m 
WHERE r.requi_id=m.requi_id AND
      m.reg_no='1401490' AND
      m.hospital_id=17004 
ORDER BY m.requi_date::date DESC,orderdate DESC,m.requi_id DESC LIMIT 1000;
```

The orderdate is sorted in this manner:

```
15/01/2016 10:45AM    
15/01/2016 10:45AM
15/01/2016 08:52PM
15/01/2016 08:52PM
```

whereas i want it as :

```
                  15/01/2016 08:52PM
                  15/01/2016 08:52PM
                  15/01/2016 10:45AM
                  15/01/2016 10:45AM
```

Please help me.

Comment: Use `ASC` instead of `DESC`?

Comment: ASC will arrrange it in ascending order..

Comment: Have you tried replacing `ORDER BY m.requi_date::date DESC,orderdate DESC` with simply `ORDER BY m.requi_date DESC`?

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting `orderdate` as a char, so it is being ordered lexically, where `6 1` > `6 0` ( in `../2016 08:52..` and `../2016 10:45..`).

I don't know the type of `m.requi_date` but I suspect it is a datetime type. So you should get the result you are after by just ordering by `m.requi_date DESC` instead of `m.requi_date DESC,orderdate DESC`.